# Remove () from the string

Tags: php, regex, string, brackets

```
$item = "(1) Robin Hood (hero)";
```

Text inside brackets can be changed.

**How do I remove all the brackets with text inside them from the string?**

We should get this:

```
$item = "Robin Hood";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` as:

```
$item = preg_replace('/\(.*?\)/s','',$item);
```

Looks like you also want to remove leading and trailing spaces after the replacement.
You can make use of `trim` for that as:

```
$item = trim( preg_replace('/\(.*?\)/s','',$item));
```

The regex used is `\(.*?\)`:

- `(` and `)` are regex meta-characters
  used for grouping. To match literal
  paranthesis you need to escape them
  by preceding them with a `\`.
- You match any arbitrary text between
  the parenthesis by using `.*?`. You
  could also do the same using `[^)]*`
- `.` by default does not match a
  newline. To make is match a newline
  we use the `s` modifier. Without it
  we would fail to do the replacement
  in `"(hello\nworld) Hi"`

Comment: what is the difference between yours and stillstanding's solution?

Comment: Why `.*?`? Wouldn't just `.*` work just as well? (`.` matches any one character, `*` repeats the specifier zero or more times, then `?` to match whether those zero or more of any characters exist or not.)